# Typescript Alert showing multiple times when not needed

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am trying to get the button to do a single alert when the button is clicked, but the button odes something strange:

> The first time I click the Login Button, the alert shows once, when I click it again the alert shows 2 times, then I click the button a 3rd time, the alert shows 3 times.
> After that, If I were to click the Forgot Password Button, the alert assigned to Forgot password would show 4 times.

I am very confused as to why this happens and how to fix it?

> .ts

```
class LoginTs{
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(username: string, password: string ) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;


        let submitBtn = document.getElementById("enter")
        submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {
            return LoginTs.validateInput(this.username,this.password)
        });


        let forgotBtn= document.getElementById("forgotPass")
        forgotBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>LoginTs.forgotPassword());
    }



    private static validateInput(username: string, password: string) {
        if(username =="billy" && password =="bronco1"){
            return alert("success")
        }
        else{
            return alert("wrong username or password")
        }
    }

    private static forgotPassword() {
        return alert("tough luck lmao")
    }
}




document.getElementById("enter").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let iUser =(document.getElementById("se") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let iPass =(document.getElementById("sp") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let loginTs = new LoginTs(iUser,iPass);
})
```

> .html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Capstone Typescript Login</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<header>
    <h2>Billy Bronco's Grading Calculator</h2>
</header>

<div id="container">

    <div id="tabs">

        <p type="button" id="lt" class="tabs" onclick="loginTabFun()">Log in</p>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Login.css">

        <div id="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="cont">

        <div id="login" class="comm">
            <h3>Sign in</h3>

            <input id="se" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input id="sp" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>

            <input type="button" class="button" id="enter" value="Login">
            <input type="button" class="button" id="forgotPass" value="Forgot Password?">
            <a href="register_view.html" > Don't have an account? CLICK HERE </a>

        </div>


    </div>

</div>
<script src="LoginTs.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

> Thank You!

Comment: Each time you click the button you instantiate a new LoginTs which binds new event listeners. They are added, not replaced.

Comment: @ChrisHeald I tried to replace it, but the buttons also take much longer to load the alert in comparison to using window.onload; I prefer to use the replacement kind of strategy, because it allows multiple inputs for both the email and password, but I don't know how to make it efficient? If you could possibly help me out in an answers I would greatly appreciate it, because I'm very new to typescript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting up new event listeners in your constructor every time the enter button is clicked. They're compounding on top of each other. Additionally, you're setting the username and password values at the wrong time. They should be set when the user tries to validate their input (clicks the submit button). The constructor should be instantiated after the html and script have loaded, eg. in a window.onload event

```
window.onload = function() {
    let loginTs = new LoginTs();
}
```

Here is your class with a couple changes. The username and password variables aren't set until the user clicks the button, since that is the point at which you want to capture them for validation.

```
class LoginTs{
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor( ) {
        // this.username = username;
        // this.password = password;


        let submitBtn = document.getElementById("enter")
        submitBtn.addEventListener("click", (e: Event) => {
            this.username =(document.getElementById("se") as HTMLInputElement).value;
            this.password =(document.getElementById("sp") as HTMLInputElement).value;

            return LoginTs.validateInput(this.username,this.password)
        });


        let forgotBtn= document.getElementById("forgotPass")
        forgotBtn.addEventListener("click",(e:Event) =>LoginTs.forgotPassword());
    }



    private static validateInput(username: string, password: string) {
        if(username =="billy" && password =="bronco1"){
            return alert("success")
        }
        else{
            return alert("wrong username or password")
        }
    }

    private static forgotPassword() {
        return alert("tough luck lmao")
    }
}



window.onload = function() {
        let loginTs = new LoginTs();
    }
```

Comment: This worked for the first time, but I realized when running it, it also gave the bug that it only returned the same alert, even if the input was changed, do you happen to know why or how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that the first time. You were capturing those values too early. The `value` of those html elements should be evaluated after the user has clicked the submit button. See the revised answer

Comment: And as such, I removed the initialization parameters of your constructor since there wasn't any point to setting username and password at construction